# How to hide some return data from RS232 Serial Port

Tags: c#, console, serial-port, firmware, .net-4.8

I am using `C# Console app` to interact with firmware on sas Expander card.

It was connected by `RS232 Serial Port`.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace SerialPortExample
{
    class SerialPortProgram
    {
        // Create the serial port with basic settings
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM5");

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1000;
            mySerialPort.Open();
            if(mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            { 
                
                mySerialPort.Write("\r");
               
            }
            
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            while (true)
            {
                string userResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userResponse == "sys")
                {
                    mySerialPort.Write("sys\r");
                }
                else if (userResponse == "counters")
                {
                    mySerialPort.Write("counters\r");
                }
                else if (userResponse == "phyinfo")
                {
                    mySerialPort.Write("phyinfo\r");
                }
                else if (userResponse == "? -a")
                {
                    mySerialPort.Write("? -a\r");
                }
                else 
                {
                    mySerialPort.Write("\r");
                }

            }
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.Write(indata);
        }
     

    }
}
```

What the app execute command `counters` result:
[image]

Using `PuTTy` by sending command `counters` result:
[image]

You can see `counters` will show up on the app page

and `counters` won't show up in `PuTTY`'s page.

What should I do to let my code result just like `PuTTY` does?

How to hide some return data from Serial Port?

My `C# Console app` is using `.Net Framwork 4.7.2`.

.....................................................

Update:

After I add `mySerialPort.ReadChar();` in code,

the code looks like:

```
 string userResponse = Console.ReadLine();
                if (userResponse == "sys")
                {
                    mySerialPort.Write("sys\r");
                    mySerialPort.ReadChar();
                    mySerialPort.ReadChar();
                    mySerialPort.ReadChar();
                }
```

and the result is:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not satisfied with this result

because there are at least twenty command in firmware.

I don't want keep adding `mySerialPort.ReadChar()` in every condition.

Is there another way to fullfill my goal？

.......................................................

Update Part2:

After adding `string echocancel = sp.ReadLine();` in  `DataReceivedHandler`,

the code looks like:

```
    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string echocancel = sp.ReadLine();
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.Write(indata);

        }
```

and the result looks like:

[image]

After `product identity :`'s word should have `default`

and between `product Identity` and `<<Alarm status>>`

should have space, it should show up.

At least, `sys` , this three character won't show up again.

Did someone has some solution about it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a situation of double echo of keyboard input.

By default the typical terminal emulation program (e.g. **minicom**) disables local echo for keyboard input; apparent **putty** does the same.
So when the attached device does echo the typed input, you only see one copy of the input displayed.
(Because of this default mode, you will not see what you type when the attached device also has its echo inhibited.)

With your program, characters typed as input on keyboard are echoed locally to your display, and when transmitted that line is echoed by the attached device and then displayed (by your program) as part of the response.

---

You can verify this hypothesis by changing your code to accept a `foo` command instead of `counters`:

```
            ...
            else if (userResponse == "foo")
            {
                mySerialPort.Write("counters\r");
            }
            ...
```

The expected display should then be something like

```
bp1 >foo
counters
...
```

---

Possible solutions are:
a. disable echo from the device (preferred), or
b. disable local echo, or
c. echo cancellation.

Echo cancellation can be simplified in your program because each command transmitted seems to be a line terminated by a carriage return.  So instead of absorbing individual characters as you did for an individual command, you only need a single read of a line to absorb the echoed line:

```
        while (true)
        {
            string userResponse = Console.ReadLine();
            if (userResponse == "sys")
            ...
            else 
            {
                mySerialPort.Write("\r");
            }
  
            /* 
             * might need a delay here allow serial output to drain/complete
             * and give device time to respond
             */
            string echocancel = mySerialPort.Readline();
        }
```

However such echo cancellation would also require proper setting of the line-terminator character, i.e. `mySerialPort.NewLine = "\r";`
See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.newline?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_NewLine

Note that disabling echo from the device is the standard mode for (serial) communication with a device by software (i.e. machine to machine).  This simply reduces the amount of data transferred. Echo is only enabled for the convenience of humans.

---

> What is the local echo in my code? Console.ReadLine()?

For Linux, **minicom** disables local echo by configuring termios flags for **stdin** (aka the keyboard).
Seems like you're using Windows, so I don't know the equivalent operation.
Yes, the local echo should be occurring during the **Console.ReadLine()**.

---

**Addendum in response to Update Part2**

My suggestion for echo cancellation guarantees that only one line of input would be discarded per command sent.
Your modification differs from my suggestion in order to keep all serial port reads within a single procedure/handler.
However that could introduce a synchronization issue, because now you have to ensure that **DataReceivedHandler()** is performed only once per iteration of the `while` loop that receives `userResponse`.
But there seems to be absolutely nothing in that `while` loop that could enforce any synchronization with **DataReceivedHandler()**.

Prior to this echo cancellation modification, your program really didn't have to rely on any synchronization.  Since **DataReceivedHandler()** simply displayed whatever it received, this data transfer seems flawless, and you weren't concerned about how `indata` aligned with the text of the response.

To test this synchronization hypothesis, report the line(s) that is/are being discarded for echo cancellation, e.g.

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string echocancel = sp.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine($"DEBUG: {echocancel}"); 
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.Write(indata);

    }
```

---

In practice echo cancellation is probably the method of last choice in comparison to simply avoiding the generation of the echo.  Some schemes validate the received data prior to discarding (e.g. using a FIFO of expected echo data) to ensure the cancellation is accurate.

---

Comment: What is the local echo in my code?Console.ReadLine()? I tried to disabled ``Console.Write(indata);`` and ``bp1>``wouldn't show up in the result.

Comment: Yes, your expected result is right. After showing``foo``,the new line word is ``counters``.My Computer's O.S. is windows 10.

Comment: I added  ``string echocancel = mySerialPort.ReadLine();`` in the code. The result comes out ``System.TimeoutException HResult=0x80131505``.Should I set ``mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;`` to 5000?

Comment: I really don't know C# at all.  I was guessing at a possible solution based on a quick search for ReadLine().

Comment: Instead of Console.ReadLine, use a combination of [Console.KeyAvailable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.keyavailable?view=net-5.0) and [Console.ReadKey(ture)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-5.0), and enter SerialPort.Write character by character including control keys such as Enter. [c# how to get key input without block](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/csharp/c%23+how+to+get+key+input+without+block)

Comment: Sorry, my Bad. It still has some problem. I'll update the question.

Comment: @kunif But how could ``Console.ReadKey`` read more than one character on keyboard? This firmware command could be complicated. In ``sys`` command, it could be typed ``sys``、``sys rev``、``sys alarm`` and ``sys hdd`` these four option.

Comment: Every time one key is pressed, one byte is sent as it is. The sender does not have to decide anything. They are the same as PuTTY's behavior. If the receiving device does not check the timeout between keystrokes, it will work fine. If you misspell it, it will either be ignored by the receiving device or you will be notified of an error message by the receiving device.